# Google Search Console API, get Top Linking Sites

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I am currently trying to develop a small script to use Google Search Console API in order to get some data from my website. I have seen lots of tutorials and tested a few approaches via php and python while trying to interact with Search Console API v3.

My main goal is to get the **Top Linking Sites** list of my website in an automated way (Google New Search Console -> Links -> Top linking sites).

I don't know if this is available via Google API. I have found nothing till now, except from getting data for clicks, ctr, impressions etc.

Is this even possible to get such list via the API?